# Unable to change @rpath on osx

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, rpath, otool, install-name-tool

I've got an external lib 'libspecial.dylib' with following dependencies.

```
otool -L libspecial.dylib                                                                                                                          [11:20:59]
libspecial.dylib:
     @rpath/libspecial.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.1)
     @rpath/libhelper.dylib  (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.1)
```

Because @rpath causes problems I have a script replacing all @rpath with the real path.

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libspecial.dylib /tmp/libspecial.dylib libspecial.dylib
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libhelper.dylib  /tmp/libhelper.dylib  libspecial.dylib
```

But this only replaces the second dependency (in fact there are more dependencies, all are replaced but not the first one which points to the lib itself):

```
otool -L libspecial.dylib
libspecial.dylib:
     @rpath/libspecial.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.1)
     /tmp/libhelper.dylib    (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.1)
```

I have no idea why I can't change the first depencdency. Any ideas?

Running on OSX 10.11.1

Comment: The first reference is a reference the the library itself, so I wouldn't expect you can change that. However, I would not expect it to have @rpath/ at the beginning either. All the dylibs I've seen start with their own name. Can you set it to just libspecial.dylib?

Comment: You're right, in the last version of this library the reference to itself was without @rpath and everything worked fine. But sadly I'm not able to change it, not to /tmp/libspecial.dylib and not to libspecial.dylib.

Comment: Doesn't that just affect the default load path when the binary links with it?  I don't *think* it matters at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I realized that the first "dependency" isn't a dependency as such, it is more the name of the lib. I can also see it when using

```
otool -D libspecial.dylib
    @rpath/libspecial.dylib
```

So the command was just wrong. It can be fixed with

```
install_name_tool -id libspecial.dylib libspecial.dylib
```